# android studio can not install apk in huawei mate8

Tags: android, android-studio

USB debug open and install apk from Android Studio failed.
It says

[image]

Who can help me?

Comment: this may help your https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/2nb1e3/secondary_users_on_lollipop_cant_install_apks/

Comment: click on `OK` button

Comment: if ok worked i will not ask for help,but thank you .

Comment: i reset the phone and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

> I think you already installed the apk with same package name in your
>   device. Try to uninstall and then install it. May be its work

Comment: i found other apk same problem if install once.